# Open Source alternative for Kafka Confluent HTTP Sink Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I want to push data from Kafka topic to REST endpoint. (non enterprise version and no confluent kafka managed service used).

I was thinking of using Confluent's Kafka Connect  HTTP sink but I realized it comes with a trial period of 30 days after which it requires a license.

Are there any other open source / free options to use as a bidirectional bridge between Apache Kafka and REST API.

Comment: If you want bidirectional, then Apache NiFi would be useful

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for a sink,
then Aiven (**DISCLAIMER**: the company I work for) [developed an Open Source HTTP Kafka Connect](https://github.com/aiven/aiven-kafka-connect-http)

Comment: Thank you, I tried Aiven Kafka HTTP Connector, but the connector is not listed after adding the plugin  (jar files after building the source code), to the kafka connect

Comment: @JISHNUTU Could you please specify how do you add the connector? I just tried to specify the path to the folder with jar files as `plugin.path` in connect properties and the connector appeared in response to http://<connect_host>:<connect_port>/connector-plugins/

Comment: yes, I followed the same step, mentioned the path of jar files in plugin.path, and I was able to add other connectors in same way. (FYI: the jar files I got after building the source code [build/distributions/], I do have doubt is those the right jar files ?)