# How to handle unconsumed message in kafka without using the DLQ

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am producing messages using kafka to the particular topic, and listening the messages using particular consumer. Inside the consumer, calling an external api that is responsible to consumed the messages.

I want to handle unconsumed messages, if the api is down or fail without stopping and restarting the consumer application. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a circuit breaker that calls pause/close on the consumer instance in that scenario.

Then some background thread to ping your service, and restart the consumer again.

Kafka doesn't come with any utilities to do this for you.

Otherwise, let the consumer fail. Disable auto commits, and data will still remain retained in the topic. However, you'll still need to pause/close to not get endless exceptions while the consumer is running.

Sidenote: Kafka Connect framework should ideally be used here instead, as it has builtin fault tolerance features

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Is it good to assign one consumer to particular consumer group that helps to track last offset commit, when the api is down during consuming the messages we can perform retries until the API is up, and when the API is up consumer starts consuming from the last unconsumed messages. ?

Comment: If you use two different groups, then they won't know about each other without extra code, so I wouldn't really recommend that. Maybe look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68440097/open-source-alternative-for-kafka-confluent-http-sink-connector